# matlab "arrayfun" function

Tags: matlab

Consider the following function, which takes a gray image (2D matrix) as input:

```
function r = fun1(img)
r = sum(sum(img));
```

I'm thinking of using `arrayfun` to process a series of images(3d matrix), thus eliminating the need for a `for` loop:

```
arrayfun(@fun1, imgStack);
```

But `arrayfun` tries to treat every element of `imgStack` as an input to `fun1`, the result of the previous operation also being a 3D matrix. How can I let `arrayfun` know that I want to repeat `fun1` only on the 3rd dimension of `imgStack`?

Another question, does `arrayfun` invoke `fun1` in parallel?

Comment: you might want to simplify your original function to `r=sum(img(:))`

Answer (score 5):

In this case, you don't need arrayfun to perform your calculation, you can simply do this:

```
imgStack = rand( 10, 10, 4 ); % 4 10x10 images
r = sum( sum( imgStack, 1 ), 2 ); % sum along both dimensions 1 and 2
```

In general, lots of MATLAB operations will operate on a whole array at once, that's the usual way of avoiding loops.

MATLAB's normal "[arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html)" is not parallel. However, for [GPUArrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/gpuarray.html) (with Parallel Computing Toolbox), there is a parallel version of [arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/arrayfun.html).

Comment: sorry for confusing, but my actual function is much more complex than 'fun1', which take image as input, and generate some results. Probably I can avoid using 'arrayfun' by modifying the function, but since it is from a toolbox, I would like to leave the function untouched.

Answer (score 0):

On your first question: 
You might try accumarray for this. One suggestion

```
function ds = applyfun_onfirstdim(arr, h_fun)

dimvec = size(arr);
indexarr = repmat( (1:dimvec(1))', [1, dimvec(2:end)] );

ds = accumarray(indexarr(:), arr(:), [], h_fun);
```

This creates an auxiliary index-array of the same dimensions as the input "arr". Every slice you want to apply h_fun to gets the same index-number. In this example it is the first.